# Gson deserialization to java object does not work

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, gson

The JSON string is `{"status":0}` or `{"status":300}` and the Java class

```
public class MyResponse {
    private Integer status;

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyResponse{" +"status=" + status +'}';
    }
}
```

When status field is an Integer it is converted to null for all incoming values. When it is of type int only 0 is deserialized correctly. Other values are converted to null.

What am I missing?

Here is how I am trying to deserialize

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
    .setPrettyPrinting().create();
gson.fromJson(json.toString(), MyResponse.class);
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you deserialize?

Comment: Have you tried commenting ``setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)`.

If you leave it, then it expects the field in your class to be named `Status` and not `status` as stated in the [documention](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html#UPPER_CAMEL_CASE): `someFieldName ---> SomeFieldName`